# Retrieve data from a link in php

Tags: php, variables

I have a popup php page that contains this link within the php file (not the browser):

http://mydomain.com/member.php?id=75

how can I get the id value only to define another variables for the users on that page?

I used the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; to get the link where user came from.

many thanks,

Comment: Is the id part of the popup url or part of the parent window (referer) url?

Comment: Parent window= member profile
popup = profile details

the popup page should take the id of Parent window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code here:

```
$query=parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
$REFERER_GET=array();
foreach(explode('&', $query) as $kv) {
    list($key,$value)=explode('=', $kv);
    $REFERER_GET[$key]=$value;
}
echo($REFERER_GET['id']);
```

Comment: @MuhammadAtieh No with `$kv` I mean key value pair. There was I small error which I fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `$getId = explode("=", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);`
Then set `$id = $getId[1]` (Since the number is going to be the second position of the array).

Comment: I tried the $_GET['id'], but it didn't worked.

 $_GET['id'], will take data from where?

since the link is in the parent page, and the GET is in popup page

Comment: I am not using `$_GET['id']`. I just named a random variable `$getId` so it would make sense. You said that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` was how you were receiving the parent link so if it is successfully retrieving http://mydomain.com/member.php?id=75 then all my code is doing is putting everything BEFORE the "=" in the first position (0) of the array `$getId`, and everything after the "=" in the second position of the `$getId` array (1). And since the value you want is all alone after the "=" you just have to set a variable, in this case `$id`, to the second position (1) of the `$getId` array

Answer (score 0):

id in your url is URL parameter which can be extracted using the $_GET variable.

just try printing $_GET variable. and choose the value of id as ($_GET["id"].

Comment: answer by webarto will work, i missed the pop up window part.